# CakePHP: calculate grand total of the whole table

Tags: jquery, mysql, cakephp

In my CakePHP 3.7.7 project have a table with the following structure:

```
class Product extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        'name' => true,
        'price' => true,
        'quantity' => true,
    ];
}
```

I just want to calculate the grand total summing up each row value (price * quantity). I don't need to group anything, all the rows should be added up. Example:

```
+------+----------+-------+
| Name | Quantity | Price |
+------+----------+-------+
| ABC  |        1 |    10 |
| DEC  |        2 |    20 |
| FEG  |        3 |    30 |
+------+----------+-------+
```

The value I want to find is 140.

[Here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-calculated-fields) it suggests to add a calculated field, but I'm not sure if it's the best way. And I cannot use a virtual field because they cannot be used in finds.
In my controller I'm trying to so something like this:

```
$query = $this->Products->find('all');
$total = $query->select(['value' => $query->func()->sum('price' * 'quantity')]);
$this->set('stockValue', $total->first()['value']);
```

but I get:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'test_db.Products.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I bet it's not a great idea to remove the `only_full_group_by` flag to overcome to my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Note that `'price' * 'quantity'` can't be correct. You are multiplying two stings in PHP, not two column values in SQL.

Comment: Show us the MySQL query which is being generated.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, thanks for pointing it out. What's the correct syntax to get the actual field values?

Comment: Try `sum('price * quantity'`). However - It shouldn't fix the givven error. If it does, then it's a really strange query builder.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, it works as the `ascsoftw`'s answer states. Would you mind to explain why it's a "really strange query builder"? Do you have another way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: @Mark ascsoftw also removed `'all'` from `find()`. Does it work for you with `find('all')`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, yes it does. And I don't see differences in the SQL generated.

Comment: Then the strange thing is: Why `sum(0)` (Note that `'price' * 'quantity'` evaluates to `0` in PHP) adds `Products.id` to the select clause? What query is generated from your original code? Try `var_dump($total)`.

Comment: The original code leads to: "SELECT Products.id AS `Products__id`, Products.name AS `Products__name`, Products.price AS `Products__price`, Products.quantity AS `Products__quantity`, (SUM(:param0)) AS `value` FROM products Products ORDER BY Products.name ASC"

Comment: Well thats the wrong query, because no-one told the query builder to include other columns in the SELECT clause or to use an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code.

```
        $query = $this->Products->find(); // Do not pass all as argument.
        $query->select(['value' => $query->func()->sum('price*quantity')]);

        $result  = $query->first();
        echo $result->value; //prints 140
```

This would produce query as below:

```
SELECT (SUM(price*quantity)) AS `value` FROM products Products LIMIT 1
```

You can confirm by using below to debug:

```
var_dump($query);
```